# Update rows in sql with new values

Tags: python, mysql

i am working on python. i want to update every row of sql with new value.
my code is:

```
val = cursor.execute("select id from tweeter1")
    words= processedRow.split()
    fdist2=len(words)
    for id1 in val:
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE TWEETER1 SET t1=%s where id = %s""",(fdist2,id1))
        db.commit()
```

when i execute this code i got an error saying:

> for id1 in val:
>   TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable

any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `"""`? What is that for?

Comment: @juergend . . . That is how Python delimits strings that allow both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the cursor object:

```
cursor.execute("select id from tweeter1")
words = processedRow.split()
fdist2 = len(words)
for id1 in cursor.fetchall():
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE TWEETER1 SET t1=%s where id = %s""",(fdist2,id1))
db.commit()
```

But as long as you change all rows to the same value, you only need to UPDATE once without any where-clause:

```
words = processedRow.split()
fdist2 = len(words)
cursor.execute("""UPDATE TWEETER1 SET t1=%s""",(fdist2,))
db.commit()
```

Comment: for id1 in cursor.fetchall() is not working in to copy different values in multiple columns. i don't want to copy same value in all columns